# corrupted file after upload in laravel public disk

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-storage

I'm using this code to upload some file to storage in laravel:

```
    $username=Auth::user()->name;
    $patz=Storage::url("users/".$username."_".Auth::user()->id);
    $now= new \Carbon\Carbon();
    $fileName = 'ddt_'.$username."_".$now->getTimestamp().'.'.$request->ddt_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $pathComplete=$request->ddt_file->storeAs($patz,$fileName);

    $ddt_file_url= new Ddt_file_url();  //salvare ddt e poi prendere id
    $ddt_file_url->fileUrl = $pathComplete;
    $ddt_file_url->fileName = $fileName;
    $ddt_file_url->company()->associate(Auth::user()->id);
    $ddt_file_url->save();
```

The file is present in the folder but the file is corrupted and when I try do dowload it this not works.

This is the code that im using for the download too:

```
@if($ddtR->ddt_file_url_id)
 <a href="{{asset(Storage::url($ddt_urls->where('id',$ddtR->ddt_file_url_id)->first()->fileUrl))}}" download="{{$ddt_urls->where('id',$ddtR->ddt_file_url_id)->first()->fileName}}">
 <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default">                                                    
      Download ddt file <span class="fa icon-icona_download-01"> 
                        </span>
 </button>
 </a>
@else
  <p>-</p>
@endif
```

I ran several `dd()` over `$patz` and `$pathComplete` to me both looks correct!

Comment: if im using a "public" disk linked to storage with this structure "/public/storage/users/userX_id" what ive to put inside $patz for using as argument as storeAs method

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solve it... I dont know if its the best and cleaner solution:
[image]